# The extension name 'webHttp' is not registered in the collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, webhttpbinding

I am Hosting REST service in IIS 6.1. The following error I am getting.

```
The extension name 'webHttp' is not registered in the collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions
```

what would be a fix for this?

Comment: Please post your config file and any relevant code.

Comment: Have you looked around online? What have you tried? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/23ce805e-fca5-4314-b6ca-af54314b8618/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving the issue, I have reregistered the service model,asp.net 2.0 and 4.0 to IIS. And In the application pool configuration(Advance settings) Enable 32-Bit Applications made true(as it is a X64 system)

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis" –i –enable
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>ServiceModelReg.exe -i
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" –i –enable
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe" -iru
```

The problem is because of 32bit applications was disabled I guess.